# Format date to specific interval in Bash

Tags: bash

Trying to figure out a way in bash to return the last completed bucket of time. Not sure how to explain it, comments below should show what I'm trying to do.

```
    day=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d "$date")
    num1=$(date -d "$day" +%s)
    num2=$(date +%s)

    if [ $num1-ge $num2]; then
     // if current time was 10:13 and the interval was set to `15 minutes`, return 10:00
     // if current time was 10:27 and interval was set to `15 minutes` return 10:15
     // if current time was 10:32 and interval was set to `30 minutes` return 10:30
     // if current time was 10:58 and interval was set to `1 hour` return 10:00
      
    fi
```

I add a single day, but want to verify that it isn't past the current time:

Comment: consider pasting your code at [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) and fix the reported syntax issues; also, consider reviewing [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update the question ... in particular, provide a working set of code, the (wrong) results (or errors) generated by your code, and the (correct) exepcted output

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks for the link to shellcheck. Looks like a really useful tool.

Comment: @markp-fuso I was just providing context to my question by giving a generic example. Whether or not the code works doesn't really matter, as I'm not looking for a specific solve. Just looking for the best approach.

Comment: @NicoleStaline : Didn't you get an error message when running this code, at the `if` line?

Comment: @user1934428 No, because this code was never ran and never will be run. It was handwritten at the time I wrote the question to provide  context as to what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Wound up with the following solution:

```
date -d @$(( (($(date +%s) + 150) / 900) * 900)) "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

900 just being the number of seconds in 15 minutes

Comment: May I ask what the `@` is doing? I found it mentioned in the man-page, but without explanation.